# Cleaner way to pass the same parameter to a method multiple times per loop in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

This is something I find myself doing a lot, so I'm curious how I could clean this sort of thing up, or find a better way to do it in general.

Let's say I have a section of code similar to this:

```
 var shareDict= new Dictionary<string, string>();

 foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
    {
        string Xshare = queryObj["XShare"].ToString();
        string Yshare = queryObj["YShare"].ToString();

        shareDict.Add(Xshare, Yshare);
    }
```

I would like to be able to make a method that does the "`queryObj[""].ToString()`" for me. It will also handle null checks and what not. Something like this:

```
private static string qObj (ManagementObject mgmObj, string field)
        {
            var o = mgmObj[field];
            if (o != null || o.ToString() != "") return objf.ToString();

            return $@"{field} N/A";
        }
```

So then my original loop can change to :

```
foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
            string Xshare = qObj(queryObj, "XShare");
            string Yshare = qObj(queryObj, "YShare");

            shareDict.Add(Xshare, Yshare);
        }
```

Which is an improvement, but it'd be nice not having to pass the same `queryObj` over and over.

I hope this example code makes sense. If there's a better way entirely to do what I'm doing, or if you think the addition of the `qObj` method is unnecessary I'd love to see a better way.

Thank you.

Comment: I personally think you are bordering on the edge of sacrificing readability for the sake of 'terser' code. However if this is something you really want to do, you could make an extension method. Google them and it will be a good learning exercise to figure out the details yourself

Comment: @Dave Imagine how readable my original loop would be if I included the != null check that my method handles? especially once the string I am passing isn't as uniform as "XShare" and "YShare". It gets messy quick. 

I will look into your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Standard way is to wrap it with a class.  Pass queryObj to the constructor, consider using an indexer to access the properties.  So it becomes var q = new QueryWrap(queryObj); var xshare = q["XShare"]; etc.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you can decare *local method* within `foreach` loop in order to *capture* `queryObj`:

```
foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get()) {
  string qObj(string key) {
    string result = queryObj[key]?.ToString();

    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) ? $@"{key} N/A" : result;
  }

  shareDict.Add(qObj("Xshare"), qObj("Yshare"));
}
```

But I don't think it's more *readable* (and maintainable) then current

```
private static string qObj (ManagementObject mgmObj, string field) {...}
```

implementation